# Git - how to keep changes from remote and not erase newer

Tags: git

I have my local machine which has some recent developments I pushed to the remote, however I forgot something was messed up when I'd pushed last time to my remote machine.

commits on github remote:
commit C - contains new files I need, but something is messed up that I need from commit B
commit B - the last commit prior to C

How can I go back to commit B on my local machine, and then apply the changes from commit C?

I have read a lot, but of all things Git confuses me the most so please help without putting me down.  I don't want to make a mistake and have to start over because I didn't understand what I read.

Comment: If I understand correctly, commit C is already based on commit B, right? Do you mean you changed something incorrectly in commit C and you want to redo something in it?

Comment: You can rollback exactly those files that were messed up to your previous commit.

Comment: No, I made other changes before that I had since wiped out.  I no longer needed them, so I basically rolled back the remote but forgot about my local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git checkout branch-name

for example if you want to go the version B and its name is temp

you do git checkout temp to obtain the version B git

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up creating a branch, then git reset --hard HEAD~1 to move the master branch back to the older commit.  Then I merged and pushed.  Seems to have worked!  Git makes me dizzy!